# long press event in grid view in android

Tags: android

I am using gridview in my android project to show images. I use 15 columns in gridview to show 20x20 small image. I want to show animation on long press event on gridview item. When i press any image in gridview then similar big image show on screen on same position.

Comment: so your problem is to handle long press event or to show animation?

Answer (score 0):

On long press simply play animation over the view. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Long Pressed event for grid view item, and want to display some thing, then just copy and paste this code in your project.

```
 grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
    {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int i, long arg3) 
    {
        //Call your desired function here, or do whatever you want

        return false;
    }

    });
}
```

Comment: You should `return true` in case you want to use `setOnItemClickListener` as well!